# Direct input in Chinese, Korean or Japanese

Tags: front-end

Sometimes I need to create a document in Japanese: I know Mathematica supports typing in Japanese. However it doesn't seem to support direct (inline) input in Japanese.

Whenever I need to convert a word in Japanese, it opens in the temporary editor like the image below.

[image: ![Image 1.]

Is there any way to support direct input in Japanese. Using Japanese language interface didn't help. I noticed that same thing occurs for typing in Chinese and Korean. Basically any language that requires conversions before confirmation on words.

[MacWiki on Mathematica](http://macwiki.osdn.jp/wiki/index.php/Mathematica) says Mathematica doesn't support direct input in Japanese. However, this post is from 2011 and I was wondering if things gotten better.